# Truncating processed html in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using v-html to strip html tags but still show the processed html. Problem is, I only want 200 characters to show. I can build truncating scripts but v-html doesn't seem to take filters. How can I achieve this?

For example:

```
// This
<div class="excerpt" v-html="body_html"></div>

// Into this
<div class="excerpt" v-html="body_html | truncate(200)"></div>
```

I tried building a striptag filter and truncate + strip the tags of a regular `<p>` but it didn't process the html. In other words, I got raw HTML back without any bold, italics, etc

For example, like this:(not my preferred method, unless you can find a way for me to improve it so I can still get rendered HTML.

```
    <div>{{strippedContent | truncate(200)}}</div>

    Vue.filter("truncate", function(value, length) {
        if (!value) return "";
        value = value.toString();
        if (value.length > length) {
            return value.substring(0, length) + "...";
        } else {
            return value;
        }
    });

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                body_html: this.post.body_html
            };
        },
        computed: {
            strippedContent() {
                let regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
                return this.body_html.replace(regex, "");
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try another (local) way from the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html ?

Global (your way) registering of the filter should be made before creating the Vue instance. Can you check it?

Upd.
Also there are bugs on working together v-html and filters:

1. "v-html does not work with filters"
   https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4352
2. "Vue filter dont work on v-html"
   https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6056

SOLUTION

In the template, replace the v-html line with

```
<div :inner-html.prop="body_html | truncate(250)"></div>
```

The striphtml filter is not needed any longer

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find the solution on the second link you provided. I didn't see that one in my research. This is a reusable vue component, so it's not really needed globally since it will carry every time I use it. But good idea on non-reusable components though.

I edited your answer to reflect the solution and so I can mark it as an answer

Comment: @LOTUSMS, thank you for editing my answer and marked it as accepted. Now I am able to add comments to questions instead of creating only answers which could be far away from solutions because of my unclear understanding some parts of questions. I hope you will understand what I wanted to say:)